# Save unity game in a Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have created a 3D game in unity using a [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/systems/horror-fps-kit-82643) and I need help changing the save feature so I can save the game in a Sqlite database, any tutorials or videos that could help?

This is the script that is provided to save the game and to load it, im not exactly sure where this is saving to but it seems to save somewhere locally.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using ThunderWire.JsonManager;
using ThunderWire.Helpers;
using HFPS.Prefs;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class SaveableDataPair
{
    public enum DataBlockType { ISaveable, Attribute }

    public DataBlockType BlockType = DataBlockType.ISaveable;
    public string BlockKey;
    public MonoBehaviour Instance;
    public string[] FieldData;

    public SaveableDataPair(DataBlockType type, string key, MonoBehaviour instance, string[] fileds)
    {
        BlockType = type;
        BlockKey = key;
        Instance = instance;
        FieldData = fileds;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Main script for Save/Load System
/// </summary>
public class SaveGameHandler : Singleton<SaveGameHandler> {

    public SaveLoadScriptable SaveLoadSettings;

    [Tooltip("Serialize player data between scenes.")]
    public bool dataBetweenScenes;

    [Tooltip("Not necessary, if you does not want Fade when scene starts or switch, leave this blank.")]
    public UIFadePanel fadeControl;

    public SaveableDataPair[] saveableDataPairs;

    private ItemSwitcher switcher;
    private Inventory inventory;
    private ObjectiveManager objectives;
    private GameObject player;

    [HideInInspector]
    public string lastSave;

    void Start()
    {
        inventory = GetComponent<Inventory>();
        objectives = GetComponent<ObjectiveManager>();
        player = GetComponent<HFPS_GameManager>().Player;
        switcher = player.GetComponentInChildren<ScriptManager>().GetScript<ItemSwitcher>();

        JsonManager.Settings(SaveLoadSettings, true);

        if (saveableDataPairs.Any(pair => pair.Instance == null))
        {
            Debug.LogError("[SaveGameHandler] Some of Saveable Instances are missing or it's destroyed. Please select Setup SaveGame again from the Tools menu!");
            return;
        }

        if (Prefs.Exist(Prefs.LOAD_STATE))
        {
            int loadstate = Prefs.Game_LoadState();

            if(loadstate == 0)
            {
                DeleteNextLvlData();
            }
            else if (loadstate == 1 && Prefs.Exist(Prefs.LOAD_SAVE_NAME))
            {
                string filename = Prefs.Game_SaveName();

                if (File.Exists(JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameSavesPath) + filename))
                {
                    JsonManager.DeserializeData(filename);
                    string loadScene = (string)JsonManager.Json()["scene"];
                    lastSave = filename;

                    if (UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == loadScene)
                    {
                        LoadSavedSceneData(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=yellow>[SaveGameHandler]</color> Could not find load file: " + filename);
                    Prefs.Game_LoadState(0);
                }
            }
            else if(loadstate == 2 && Prefs.Exist(Prefs.LOAD_SAVE_NAME) && dataBetweenScenes)
            {
                JsonManager.ClearArray();
                Prefs.Game_SaveName("_NextSceneData.sav");

                if (File.Exists(JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameDataPath) + "_NextSceneData.sav"))
                {
                    JsonManager.DeserializeData(FilePath.GameDataPath, "_NextSceneData.sav");
                    LoadSavedSceneData(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void DeleteNextLvlData()
    {
        if (File.Exists(JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameDataPath) + "_NextSceneData.sav"))
        {
            File.Delete(JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameDataPath) + "_NextSceneData.sav");
        }
    }

    /* SAVE GAME SECTION */
    public void SaveGame(bool allData)
    {
        JsonManager.ClearArray();
        Dictionary<string, object> playerData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> slotData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> shortcutData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> objectivesData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        /* PLAYER PAIRS */
        if (allData)
        {
            JsonManager.AddPair("scene", UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            JsonManager.AddPair("dateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

            playerData.Add("playerPosition", player.transform.position);
            playerData.Add("cameraRotation", player.GetComponentInChildren<MouseLook>().GetRotation());
        }

        playerData.Add("playerHealth", player.GetComponent<HealthManager>().Health);
        /* END PLAYER PAIRS */

        /* ITEMSWITCHER PAIRS */
        Dictionary<string, object> switcherData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "switcherActiveItem", switcher.currentItem },
            { "switcherLightObject", switcher.currentLightObject },
            { "switcherWeaponItem", switcher.weaponItem }
        };

        foreach (var Item in switcher.ItemList)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> ItemInstances = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var Instance in Item.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>().Where(x => typeof(ISaveableArmsItem).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())).ToArray())
            {
                ItemInstances.Add(Instance.GetType().Name.Replace(" ", "_"), (Instance as ISaveableArmsItem).OnSave());
                switcherData.Add("switcher_item_" + Item.name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_"), ItemInstances);
            }
        }
        /* END ITEMSWITCHER PAIRS */

        /* INVENTORY PAIRS */
        foreach (var slot in inventory.Slots)
        {
            if (slot.GetComponent<InventorySlot>().itemData != null)
            {
                InventoryItemData itemData = slot.GetComponent<InventorySlot>().itemData;
                Dictionary<string, object> itemDataArray = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "slotID", itemData.slotID },
                    { "itemID", itemData.item.ID },
                    { "itemAmount", itemData.m_amount },
                    { "itemData", itemData.customData }
                };

                slotData.Add("inv_slot_" + inventory.Slots.IndexOf(slot), itemDataArray);
            }
            else
            {
                slotData.Add("inv_slot_" + inventory.Slots.IndexOf(slot), "null");
            }
        }

        Dictionary<string, object> inventoryData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "inv_slots_count", inventory.Slots.Count },
            { "slotsData", slotData }
        };

        /* INVENTORY SHORTCUTS PAIRS */
        if (inventory.Shortcuts.Count > 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> shortcutsData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var shortcut in inventory.Shortcuts)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> shortcutsDataPairs = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "itemID", shortcut.item.ID },
                    { "shortcutKey", shortcut.shortcutKey.ToString() }
                };

                shortcutsData.Add("shortcut_" + shortcut.slot, shortcutsDataPairs);
            }

            inventoryData.Add("shortcutsData", shortcutsData);
        }

        /* INVENTORY FIXED CONTAINER PAIRS */
        if (inventory.FixedContainerData.Count > 0)
        {
            inventoryData.Add("fixedContainerData", inventory.GetFixedContainerData());
        }
        /* END INVENTORY PAIRS */

        /* OBJECTIVE PAIRS */
        if (objectives.objectiveCache.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var obj in objectives.objectiveCache)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> objectiveData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "toComplete", obj.toComplete },
                    { "isCompleted", obj.isCompleted }
                };

                objectivesData.Add(obj.identifier.ToString(), objectiveData);
            }
        }
        /* END OBJECTIVE PAIRS */

        //Add data pairs to serialization buffer
        JsonManager.AddPair("playerData", playerData);
        JsonManager.AddPair("itemSwitcherData", switcherData);
        JsonManager.AddPair("inventoryData", inventoryData);
        JsonManager.AddPair("objectivesData", objectivesData);

        //Add all saveables
        if (allData && saveableDataPairs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var Pair in saveableDataPairs)
            {
                if(Pair.BlockType == SaveableDataPair.DataBlockType.ISaveable)
                {
                    var data = (Pair.Instance as ISaveable).OnSave();
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        JsonManager.AddPair(Pair.BlockKey, data);
                    }
                }
                else if (Pair.BlockType == SaveableDataPair.DataBlockType.Attribute)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> attributeFieldPairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    if (Pair.FieldData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var Field in Pair.FieldData)
                        {
                            FieldInfo fieldInfo = Pair.Instance.GetType().GetField(Field);

                            if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(Color) || fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(KeyCode))
                            {
                                if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(Color))
                                {
                                    attributeFieldPairs.Add(GetAttributeKey(fieldInfo), string.Format("#{0}", ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA((Color)Pair.Instance.GetType().InvokeMember(Field, BindingFlags.GetField, null, Pair.Instance, null))));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    attributeFieldPairs.Add(GetAttributeKey(fieldInfo), Pair.Instance.GetType().InvokeMember(Field, BindingFlags.GetField, null, Pair.Instance, null).ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                attributeFieldPairs.Add(GetAttributeKey(fieldInfo), Pair.Instance.GetType().InvokeMember(Field, BindingFlags.GetField, null, Pair.Instance, null));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Empty Fields Data: " + Pair.BlockKey);
                    }

                    JsonManager.AddPair(Pair.BlockKey, attributeFieldPairs);
                }
            }
        }

        //Serialize all pairs from buffer
        SerializeSaveData(!allData);
    }

    /* LOAD SECTION */
    void LoadSavedSceneData(bool allData)
    {
        if (allData)
        {
            var posToken = JsonManager.Json()["playerData"]["playerPosition"];
            player.transform.position = posToken.ToObject<Vector3>();

            var rotToken = JsonManager.Json()["playerData"]["cameraRotation"];
            player.GetComponentInChildren<MouseLook>().SetRotation(rotToken.ToObject<Vector2>());
        }

        var healthToken = JsonManager.Json()["playerData"]["playerHealth"];
        player.GetComponent<HealthManager>().Health = (float)healthToken;

        switcher.currentLightObject = (int)JsonManager.Json()["itemSwitcherData"]["switcherLightObject"];
        switcher.weaponItem = (int)JsonManager.Json()["itemSwitcherData"]["switcherWeaponItem"];

        //Deserialize ItemSwitcher Item Data
        foreach (var Item in switcher.ItemList)
        {
            JToken ItemToken = JsonManager.Json()["itemSwitcherData"]["switcher_item_" + Item.name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_")];

            foreach (var Instance in Item.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>().Where(x => typeof(ISaveableArmsItem).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())).ToArray())
            {
                (Instance as ISaveableArmsItem).OnLoad(ItemToken[Instance.GetType().Name.Replace(" ", "_")]);
            }
        }

        //Deserialize ItemSwitcher ActiveItem
        int switchID = (int)JsonManager.Json()["itemSwitcherData"]["switcherActiveItem"];
        if (switchID != -1)
        {
            switcher.ActivateItem(switchID);
        }

        //Deserialize Inventory Data
        StartCoroutine(DeserializeInventory(JsonManager.Json()["inventoryData"]));

        //Deserialize Objectives
        if (JsonManager.HasKey("objectivesData"))
        {
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> objectivesData = JsonManager.Json<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>(JsonManager.Json()["objectivesData"].ToString());

            foreach (var obj in objectivesData)
            {
                objectives.AddObjectiveModel(new ObjectiveModel(obj.Key, int.Parse(obj.Value["toComplete"]), bool.Parse(obj.Value["isCompleted"])));
            }
        }

        //Deserialize saveables 
        if (allData)
        {
            foreach (var Pair in saveableDataPairs)
            {
                JToken token = JsonManager.Json()[Pair.BlockKey];

                if (token == null) continue;

                if (Pair.BlockType == SaveableDataPair.DataBlockType.ISaveable)
                {
                    if (Pair.Instance.GetType() == typeof(SaveObject) && (Pair.Instance as SaveObject).saveType == SaveObject.SaveType.ObjectActive)
                    {
                        bool enabled = token["obj_enabled"].ToObject<bool>();
                        Pair.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(enabled);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (Pair.Instance as ISaveable).OnLoad(token);
                    }
                }
                else if (Pair.BlockType == SaveableDataPair.DataBlockType.Attribute)
                {
                    foreach (var Field in Pair.FieldData)
                    {
                        SetValue(Pair.Instance, Pair.Instance.GetType().GetField(Field), JsonManager.Json()[Pair.BlockKey][GetAttributeKey(Pair.Instance.GetType().GetField(Field))]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* LOAD SECTION INVENTORY */
    private IEnumerator DeserializeInventory(JToken token)
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => inventory.Slots.Count > 0);

        int slotsCount = (int)token["inv_slots_count"];
        int neededSlots = slotsCount - inventory.Slots.Count;

        if(neededSlots != 0)
        {
            inventory.ExpandSlots(neededSlots);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            JToken slotToken = token["slotsData"]["inv_slot_" + i];
            string slotString = slotToken.ToString();

            if (slotString != "null")
            {
                inventory.AddItemToSlot((int)slotToken["slotID"], (int)slotToken["itemID"], (int)slotToken["itemAmount"], slotToken["itemData"].ToObject<CustomItemData>());
            }
        }

        //Deserialize Shortcuts
        if (token["shortcutsData"] != null && token["shortcutsData"].HasValues)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> shortcutsData = token["shortcutsData"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

            foreach (var shortcut in shortcutsData)
            {
                int slot = int.Parse(shortcut.Key.Split('_')[1]);
                inventory.ShortcutBind(int.Parse(shortcut.Value["itemID"]), slot, (KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), shortcut.Value["shortcutKey"]));
            }
        }

        //Deserialize FixedContainer
        if (token["fixedContainerData"] != null && token["fixedContainerData"].HasValues)
        {
            var fixedContainerData = token["fixedContainerData"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, JToken>>();

            foreach (var item in fixedContainerData)
            {
                inventory.FixedContainerData.Add(new ContainerItemData(inventory.GetItem(item.Key), (int)item.Value["item_amount"], item.Value["item_custom"].ToObject<CustomItemData>()));
            }
        }
    }

    string GetAttributeKey(FieldInfo Field)
    {
        SaveableField saveableAttr = Field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SaveableField), false).Cast<SaveableField>().SingleOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveableAttr.CustomKey))
        {
            return Field.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            return saveableAttr.CustomKey;
        }
    }

    void SetValue(object instance, FieldInfo fInfo, JToken token)
    {
        Type type = fInfo.FieldType;
        string value = token.ToString();
        if (type == typeof(string)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, value);
        if (type == typeof(int)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, int.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(uint)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, uint.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(long)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, long.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(ulong)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, ulong.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(float)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, float.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(double)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, double.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(bool)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, bool.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(char)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, char.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(short)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, short.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(byte)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, byte.Parse(value));
        if (type == typeof(Vector2)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, token.ToObject(type));
        if (type == typeof(Vector3)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, token.ToObject(type));
        if (type == typeof(Vector4)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, token.ToObject(type));
        if (type == typeof(Quaternion)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, token.ToObject(type));
        if (type == typeof(KeyCode)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, Parser.Convert<KeyCode>(value));
        if (type == typeof(Color)) fInfo.SetValue(instance, Parser.Convert<Color>(value));
    }

    public void SaveNextSceneData(string scene)
    {
        Prefs.Game_LoadState(2);
        Prefs.Game_LevelName(scene);
        JsonManager.ClearArray();
        SaveGame(false);
    }

    async void SerializeSaveData(bool betweenScenes)
    {
        string filepath = JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameSavesPath);
        GetComponent<HFPS_GameManager>().ShowSaveNotification();

        if (!betweenScenes)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(filepath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
                FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("Save?.sav");

                if (fi.Length > 0)
                {
                    string SaveName = "Save" + fi.Length;
                    lastSave = SaveName + ".sav";
                    FileStream file = new FileStream(JsonManager.GetCurrentPath() + SaveName + ".sav", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    await Task.Run(() => JsonManager.SerializeJsonDataAsync(file));
                }
                else
                {
                    lastSave = "Save0.sav";
                    FileStream file = new FileStream(JsonManager.GetCurrentPath() + "Save0.sav", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    await Task.Run(() => JsonManager.SerializeJsonDataAsync(file));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(JsonManager.GetCurrentPath());

                lastSave = "Save0.sav";
                FileStream file = new FileStream(JsonManager.GetCurrentPath() + "Save0.sav", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                await Task.Run(() => JsonManager.SerializeJsonDataAsync(file));
            }

            Prefs.Game_SaveName(lastSave);
            DeleteNextLvlData();
        }
        else
        {
            DeleteNextLvlData();
            FileStream file = new FileStream(JsonManager.GetFilePath(FilePath.GameDataPath) + "_NextSceneData.sav", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            await Task.Run(() => JsonManager.SerializeJsonDataAsync(file, true));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please research your structure. You have created a game based on an FPS kit, yes? This means that you have a working game, and save features are typically applied with XML or similar formats.

I recommend utilising C# (Unity's native tongue) to implement something like the MySQL Connector for .NET/Mono and translate the elements. I'm not sure if the kit you used has the features baked in, but if you have access to the source (.cs) then you can see where it is saving, and possibly create a DB structure.

What I would look at are the following components:

**Table Structure**

- What are you storing?
- The most common components are Inventory items (ammo, life, stamina, consumables, etc.). To store these, perhaps use a loading system to identify each inventory item by a code (like Bethesda's Hex Cell IDs).
- How are you storing it? How much data is needed?

**Normalisation**

- Always avoid duplicate values
- Always reference things where possible instead of creating a new value (change the value once, change it everywhere)

There's a lot to think about, but before jumping into copying and pasting code, please read up on proper database procedures - it'll help you out a lot :)

Some reading material:

- https://medium.com/@rizasif92/sqlite-and-unity-how-to-do-it-right-31991712190
- http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-save-data-in-SQLite-in-Unity3d/6357/
- https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Best of luck!